# Is a reborn (Earthen) - Reincarnate limited to 1 single skill from the other race?

Tags: arianrhod-2e

After reading through the skill Earthen: Reincarnate I'm a bit unsure. It gives you the character creation takeable skill of another race. So far so good.

BUT does that also mean, that you can also take the (non char creation only / thus non making) skills from said other race?

*(Fluff wise as you are reborn as a member of that other race I would say it makes sense. But ruleswise I'm a bit unsure...leaning towards "no").*

Can anyone clarify this?